# How do you Invoke methods on ArrayList using its FieldInfo (Reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

In my code, I declare one ArrayList within a ParentClass

```
public class ParentClass {
...
public ArrayList hybridElem; 
...
```

and then using Reflection that runs off the ParentClass, I am able to successfully obtain FieldInfo for this ArrayList @ runtime.

Using that FieldInfo, I want to be able to add or read elements from the hybridElem. 
I am able to obtain all relevant PropertyInfo of ArrayList such as .Item, .Count, .ToArray etc etc ...  and also obtain getters and setters for these properties.

Unfortunately, none of them are being successfully invoked because MethodInfo.Invoke expects Object reference to ArrayList

Any Solutions?

Comment: You know ArrayList is obsolete, right?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's incredible that there's people using it yet. It's not a good approach for collection since .NET 2.0!! It has been a very very long time this...

Comment: Generic Collections that aren't interoperable with COM are much better. Unless you're using COM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily enough. However, as the comments rightfully stated, I suggest you to switch from `ArrayList` to a generic collection.

```
var instance = new ParentClass();
var fieldInfo = instance.GetType().GetProperty("MyList");
var arrayList = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance) as ArrayList;
var count = arrayList.Count;
```

With:

```
public class ParentClass
{
    public ArrayList MyList { get; set; }

    public ParentClass()
    {
        MyList = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, to adapt it to your class which uses a field (assuming that said field is initialized somewhere):

```
var instance = new ParentClass();
var fieldInfo = instance.GetType().GetField("hybridElem");
var arrayList = fieldInfo.GetValue(instance) as ArrayList;
var count = arrayList.Count;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, John and  Eve!!. I just want to confirm that one thing that when I call fieldInfo.GetValue(instance), I will get reference to the arraylist?  Through reflection, I want to be able to add elements into Arraylist.  As for for the choice of ArrayList, with no attempt at being defensive, I did not actually choose to use the ArrayList and I am yet to complete a month in this project. At first glance, I do see merit in using ArrayList because Type of objects  being inserted to ArrayList are not limited and list is a rather disjoint and dynamic.

Comment: I will certainly take this point of switching from ArrayList to Generic and get approval from highers.

Comment: @user1972185 Yes, the result of `GetValue` will return the reference to *that* `ArrayList` and not a copy of it.

Comment: Ooops!!, I had gotten myself confused because I assumed "GetValue" Method to return value-type of the Field and not a reference to it

Comment: @user1972185 If the answer fits your needs, you can mark it as chosen by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Yes, Eve the answer worked... Sorry for delay in replying... Actually lot has changed.... From ArrayList, we went to Generic<> classses, from there to generic interface and now we are using Reflection.Emit to write code @ run time....